# Laravel 5 One-to-many relationship master and parent data CRUD

Tags: laravel-5, one-to-many, crud

I have a purchase table with date and comments and a purchasedetail table with purchaseId as a foreign key of purchase table. Have the relation in both model table is :

Purchase model:-

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Purchase extends Model {
public function purchasedetails() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Purchasedetail', 'PurchaseId', 'Id');
}
  }
```

and the
Purchasedetail model :-

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Purchasedetail extends Model {
public function purchase() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Purchase', 'PurchaseId', 'Id');
}
}
```

How can I create, update and delete both table data with relations? 
My main problem is when I send data to controller and try to create, master page data is created but it can not create parent table data or update it.
I am using Laravel 5.

Some code of my controller:

```
$purchase = new Purchase();
    $purchase->Date = Input::get('Date');
    $purchase->Comment = Input::get('Comment');
    $purchase->purchasedetails = Input::get('Purchasedetail');
$purchase-> save();

if (count($purchase->purchasedetails) != 0) {
foreach ($purchase->purchasedetails as $v) {
    $purchasedetail = new Purchasedetail();
    $purchasedetail->ItemId = $v->ItemId;
return $v->ItemId;
    }
}
$purchase-> Purchasedetail()->save($purchasedetail);
```

I get this error in return:

> ErrorException in helpers.php line 703: preg_replace(): Parameter
>   mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array. That
>   means $purchase->save() can not possible. Here i get an array list
>   from Input::get('Purchasedetail').

So what can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$purchase = new Purchase();
$purchase->Date = Input::get('Date');
$purchase->Comment = Input::get('Comment');

$purchase-> save();

$purchase->purchasedetails = Input::get('Purchasedetail');
foreach ($purchase->purchasedetails as $row) {
    $purchasedetail = new Purchasedetail();
    $purchasedetail->ItemId = $row['ItemId'];
    $purchasedetail->GradeId = $row['GradeId'];
    $purchasedetail->Quantity = $row['Quantity'];
    $purchase->purchasedetails()->save($purchasedetail);
}
```

Comment: Well it store only one singel data and all other data are define null as ItemId is null in db where it should be 1. I need to insert a list of data. In Input::get('Purchasedetail') it actually get a array-list of data not a single row.

Comment: Your code is good but in that only Id and Purchase_Id are insert in purchasedetails table. what about other data. as example i have ItemId,Quantity, in detail table. i work with ur code as like this:                 foreach(Input::get('Purchasedetail') as $purchasedetails) {
 $purchasedetail = new Purchasedetail();
 $purchasedetail->ItemId = $purchasedetails->ItemId;
 $purchasedetail->GradeId = $purchasedetails->GradeId;
 $purchasedetail->Quantity = $purchasedetails->Quantity;
 
    $purchase->purchasedetails()->save($purchasedetail);
}     .....but now no data insert. can u please ans why?

Comment: Sorry, but not work. code is ....... foreach(Input::get('Purchasedetail') as $purchasedetails) {

$purchase->purchasedetails()->save([
    'ItemId' => $input['ItemId'],
    'Quantity' => $input['Quantity'],
    'Unit'=> $input['Unit'],
    
]);

}..................and it says ,,,,MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207

Comment: Route::post('/storePurchase', 'PurchaseController@store');

Comment: Route::post('/storePurchase', 'PurchaseController@store');  and i just update my code as like that ,$purchaselines = new Collection();
$purchase->purchasedetails = Input::get('Purchasedetail');

    foreach ($purchase->purchasedetails as $row) {
return $row;
        $purchaselines->push([
          new Purchasedetail([
            'ItemId' => $row->ItemId,
            'Quanity'=> $row->Quanity])
           // 'sale_price'   => $row->price
        ]);
    }

    $purchase->purchasedetails()->saveMany($purchaselines);     but it says MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:

Comment: Oka ,,,i got it,,though i am not happy with my code but it is running now... code: $purchase->purchasedetails = Input::get('Purchasedetail');
foreach ($purchase->purchasedetails as $row) {

$purchasedetail = new Purchasedetail();
 $purchasedetail->ItemId = $row['ItemId'];
 $purchasedetail->GradeId = $row['GradeId'];
 $purchasedetail->Quantity = $row['Quantity'];
    
$purchase->purchasedetails()->save($purchasedetail);
//purchasedetail()->save($purchasedetail);
},,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, kotapeter just add the foreach in your ans and i will accept it and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am now sure, but you can to something like this.

```
 $purchase = new Purchase();
 ...
 $purchaseDetails = new PurchaseDetails();
 $purchaseDetails->purchaseId = $purchase->id;
 $purchaseDetails->save();
```